# How to create a splash screen in Java?

Tags: java, awt, splash-screen

I'm new to Java. I need to add a splash screen and It should be checking the database existence when it's running. How could I do this with Java?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do some Googling, you will find plenty of info

Comment: Are you using Swing? Are you writing a GUI framework by hand?

Comment: I need to do this with Java swing. I'm writing it with netbeans. I got so many threads in Google. But that database or something initialization part is not with it!

Comment: you are trying write some of code?? if yes, please share here to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at this url
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Then your problem with the splash screen is solved :-).